# Is getifaddrs function available in Lazarus IDE?

Tags: networking, connection, lazarus

I would like to know if getifaddrs function is available in Lazarus IDE. If so, could someone tell me in which library file it resides in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no portable implementation of that function in Lazarus/FPC. (not even cross Unix, let alone beyond)

Comment: Marco, so what you are saying is that there is no way to write a Freepascal code that will retrieve list of all the available or active network connections on your system. However, I was able to write a C code that will do just that.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that the OS provides headers in C, and not in Pascal. If they don't come with the Pascal development system (translated), you will have to translate them yourself. Usually the types/structures are harder than the function calls.